# Within group by percentage calculation in pandas Dataframe

Tags: pandas, group-by, percentage

```
    import pandas as pd

#create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'team': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
                   'status':['yes','yes','no','no','yes','no','no','yes','no','yes'],
                   'month':['m1','m2','m3','m2','m1','m3','m2','m1','m3','m1'],
                   'points': [12, 29, 34, 14, 10, 11, 7, 36, 34, 22]})

#view DataFrame
print(df)
```

Tried with below code

```
    x = df.groupby(['team','month','status']).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'cnt'}).pivot(index='team',columns=['month','status'])
x = x.fillna(0)
x
```

[image: Sample output]

**Expected Output is within groupby % calculation**

for every month m1 or m2 or m3 consider calculate yes% and no% . for example

for m1 and team A yes% 100% and no% should 0%
m2 and team A yes% 100% and no% should 0%
m3 and team A yes% 50% and no% should be 50%
similarly for team B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) with `normalize` - but output is different:

```
x = pd.crosstab([df['team'], df['month']], df['status'], normalize='index').mul(100)

print (x)
status         no    yes
team month              
A    m1       0.0  100.0
     m2      50.0   50.0
     m3     100.0    0.0
B    m1       0.0  100.0
     m2     100.0    0.0
     m3     100.0    0.0
```

If need new columns for percentages:

```
x = pd.crosstab([df['team'], df['month']], df['status'])

x = pd.concat([x, x.div(x.sum(axis=1), axis=0).add_suffix('_%').mul(100)], axis=1)
print (x)
status      no  yes   no_%  yes_%
team month                       
A    m1      0    2    0.0  100.0
     m2      1    1   50.0   50.0
     m3      1    0  100.0    0.0
B    m1      0    2    0.0  100.0
     m2      1    0  100.0    0.0
     m3      2    0  100.0    0.0
```

Another idea with [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html):

```
x = (df.groupby(['team','month'])['status'].value_counts(normalize=True)
       .unstack('status', fill_value=0)
       .mul(100))
print (x)
status         no    yes
team month              
A    m1       0.0  100.0
     m2      50.0   50.0
     m3     100.0    0.0
B    m1       0.0  100.0
     m2     100.0    0.0
     m3     100.0    0.0
```

Your ouput:

```
g = df.groupby(['team','month'])['status']
x = (pd.concat([g.value_counts(normalize=True).rename('%').mul(100),
                g.value_counts().rename('no')], axis=1)
        .unstack(['month','status'], fill_value=0)
       )
print (x)
            %                      no          
month      m1     m2           m3  m1 m2     m3
status    yes     no   yes     no yes no yes no
team                                           
A       100.0   50.0  50.0  100.0   2  1   1  1
B       100.0  100.0   0.0  100.0   2  1   0  2
```

---

```
g = df.groupby(['team','month'])['status']
x = (pd.concat([g.value_counts(normalize=True).rename('%').mul(100),
                g.value_counts().rename('no')], axis=1)
       .unstack(fill_value=0)
       .stack()
       .unstack(['month','status']))
print (x)
          %                                 no                  
month    m1            m2           m3      m1     m2     m3    
status   no    yes     no   yes     no  yes no yes no yes no yes
team                                                            
A       0.0  100.0   50.0  50.0  100.0  0.0  0   2  1   1  1   0
B       0.0  100.0  100.0   0.0  100.0  0.0  0   2  1   0  2   0
```

---

```
x = (pd.crosstab([df['team'], df['month']], df['status'], normalize='index')
       .stack()
       .mul(100)
       .unstack(['month','status']))

print (x)
month    m1            m2           m3     
status   no    yes     no   yes     no  yes
team                                       
A       0.0  100.0   50.0  50.0  100.0  0.0
B       0.0  100.0  100.0   0.0  100.0  0.0
```

Comment: Can i pass list of column names to make this dynamic .

Comment: @NabiShaikh - Somethif like second paragraph? answer was edited.